# Trying to remove tub spout but keeps rotating. No set screw

Tags: bathtub, spout

my tub spout was wobbly so i was going to remove it and put in some locktight in the hole between the pipe and the wall but have run into a problem. My tub spout wont come out. I dont see a set screw and no matter how many time i twist the spout, it never comes out. Im not a plumber and have very limited knowledge in this field. Id appreciate any advice on how to handle this situation.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post a photo

Comment: Just added them

Comment: You do not want to use Loctite. If it is wobbly but is not leaking, carefully evaluate before you do anythinng. The spout requires special plumbing products. Do not improvise. If you keep twisting it, you might loosen a joint in the wall and cause a leak in the wall. When you engage the shower diverter, do you get a strong shower flow?

Comment: @JimStewart i was planning on following this video to resolve the loose tub spout problem. https://youtu.be/TUnuSEVCAQo?si=u4aUl85Pxn21UGWM is there a better way?

Comment: I was also horrified when you talked about using loctite. But let me step back and explain, that as an old, I think of thread locker when the word loctite comes up. Now, "loctite power grab" (construction adhesive) is a brand extension that the monsters at Henkel Corp saw fit to foist on the buying public. So, at the end of the day, I pity the fool that has to clean up after the caulking job, but it should be somewhat adequate.

Comment: Loctite make a lot of products; I thought you meant a Loctite glue. There are different ways these tub spouts attach and seal to the pipe. You need to find out exactly how this one does.

Comment: @JimStewart To answer your other questions. I still seem to be getting good pressure from the shower head. The diverter is also leaking so i was going to see if i could clean it or just get a new spout.  At this point it seems like i may need an actual plumber based on what you all are saying

Comment: @JimStewart do you have any recommendations on how to find out how the spout is sealed to the pipe?

Comment: They don't put the little cut out at the wall side there for no reason.  Looking into that gap I see brass not your copper supply.  I'd guess there is an interior piece that is holding onto the pipe and does have some kind of set screw in it.  You should rotate the spout while looking for a set screw or something to loose within that relief hole.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger. Ive tried rotating it a quarter turn all around and used a flashlight to try and find a set screw. Is it possible for the set screw to have moved?

Comment: If you pull on the spout does it slide off? This kind of spout may seal near the outer end near the diverter plunger. There a hole on the underside of the spout there. Twist the spout and see if a screw appears as you turn it.  Look with a light and a mirror.

Comment: @tess since the slot in the spout only allows access to an adjustment mechanism that isn't part of the chrome spout, if there is a missing set screw it is in the brass piece and you'd see a hole.  To me it looks like you might a one of these tub spout adapters - https://www.amazon.ca/RP33794-Adapter-Faucet-Diverter-Replacement/dp/B0C3R44D9S

Comment: Also see https://youtu.be/v2O17bWA81w?si=A5yRJOheZ5rN-SDi

Comment: Kevin O'Connor is  pleasant communicator but not an expert or even especially knowledgeable plumber. He uses wrong terminology and he winds PTFE tape on the wrong direction (CCW). It is supposed to be wound on CW. Copper pipe with or without a screw fitting is not a pipe "nipple".  he does discuss some of the different ways these spouts can be attached. AFIK *any* slide-on spout will have a set screw. Be careful you are not unscrewing a pipe thread or a fitting inside the wall. This would leak inside the wall, could go unnoticed for some time. usually the tub pipe is NOT threaded inside wall